# Text running off the screen in QML, Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I have a problem in Blackberry Native. The text id is a QString, and it contains many words, and I am not sure how to code it such that the text does not run off the screen. I tried LabelTextFitMode and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
    Label { 
            text: "Description:"
            textStyle.fontWeight: FontWeight.Normal
            textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.Small
            textStyle.color: Color.DarkRed // Show this text
        } 
        Label {
            id: description // Name this as type_label so that the property alias above can set the text property of this item
            //textStyle.fontSize: FontSize.Small
            textFit {
                mode: LabelTextFitMode.FitToBounds
            }


        }
```

Comment: Do you want it multiline?

Comment: Yes I would like it to multiline. How would I do something like that?

Comment: Have you tried using a TextArea?

Comment: How would I use TextArea?

Comment: Same way as a Label, but make it not editable.  But a multi-line Label will probably do the job just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just use multiline like this:

```
Label {
   id: description 
   multiline: true
}
```

Comment: Hmm the text still runs off the screen with multiline: true

Comment: It shouldn't. You must be using more parameters for your label, please add them

Comment: Ahh ok. I'm fairly new to QML. What parameters would I use for my label?

Comment: No, you must be using something more than you showed. Please add container as well, otherwise I can't see what's happening.